# Primefaces fileUpload does not work well on huge number of file

Tags: jsf, primefaces

When I trying to upload more then 1.000 files with `fileUpload` component (like 5.000), it start having strange behavior.
It does not complete the upload (some file remain stuck in the list), the only way to start it over is add a new file. After that it start upload also the previous ones. 
Some of them are not uploaded at all, randomly.

Is there a limit? How can I control that?

Comment: Upload 1000 files at once via multi file upload? I think it is not designed for that. Not designed not to support it but also not designed to support it. Might even be that the server side has limits (servlet engine). Might even be the client has a limitation or a combination. Try to debug and see if e.g. there are stuck threads (client or server side). If there is more info maybe we get get further in the analysis...

Comment: @Kukeltje: the scope of the app is to process file, from a few to large amount. Do you have any suggestion for a different solution to upload file using a gui?

Comment: Have the client zip them and upload?

Comment: @Kukeltje: Could be an idea, but make life hard for who use the app, and depend also on the dimension of the zip: I should probably also force them to limit the size, and split in several file. Should exist a better solution

Comment: Sorry, but a hanging application is more problematic than a 'right click and zip on a 1000's files. And yes, the zip format is relevant then...

Comment: I am facing the same problem, want to upload more then 1000 files. Is there any workaround? Any suggestions is helpful

Comment: no, you cannot use it for so many files, or I was unable to find out a solution

Answer (score 1):

You can try to control limit with `fileLimit=""` but maybe it won't help you. I think it's really a bad idea to use this element for uploading so many files.

Comment: fileLimit won't help. I agree that is not a good idea, but I haven't find other solution to do it. I'm investigating to upload file using a side ftp server, but need to be driven by the java application. Any suggestion is helpful