# Is it possibile for primefaces fileUpload to not show the file detail but a total progress bar?

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I'm trying to upload a huge quantity of file (thousands), and even if it's working (in auto mode), my browser stuck at the end of the upload process.
I suspect that the problem is in the really big list of files to be updated.
Is there any chance to have the component working without showing the details of each single file?

Comment: Like said in your other question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53396931/primefaces-fileupload-does-not-work-well-on-huge-number-of-file. The component is not developed for this usecase so. But you could try to change the JS and server side java of the component. The source is open

Comment: thanks for the clue